# Литература для изучения сетевого программирования на C#

Tags: c#, .net

Подскажите пожалуйста литературу, желательно от 2012-2013 года, для изучения сетевого программирования, а точнее для написания клиент-серверных приложений. Также какую технологию лучше изучать? Знаю, что asp.net - технология построения сайтов и порталов, взаимодействующих с пользователем через браузер, а какая (развивающаяся, популярная) технология используются для построения приложений, работающих через стандартное окно программы?

Comment: не согласен, из того списка литературы не понятно, какие технологии используются для сетевого взаимодействия. Книги по WCF найдёт тот, кто знает зачем WCF нужен в общих чертах.

Answer (score 0):

Рассмотрим 3 типа приложений

1. Web приложения
2. Desktop приложения (стандартное окно программы)
3. Мобильные приложения

Наиболее распространённая технология используемая во всех трёх типах приложений это http **REST WEB API**. Для транспорта использует только протокол HTTP, HTTPS.

Для создания Web Api сервиса ищи ASP.NET MVC WebApi.

если говорить про microsoft то вторая по популярности технология это **wcf** используется преимущественно для Desktop приложений.

Имеет большие возможности, по настройки транспорта(на уровне сетевых протоколов), настройка безопасности (авторизация и шифрование).

Литература по WCF
Microsoft .NET Remoting, Скотт Маклин, Джеймс Нафтел, Ким Уильямс
Создание служб WCF, Джувел Леве (Переводчики: Е. Матвеев, А. Пасечник)

Есть ещё для работы с новый протоколом web-socket библиотека **SignalR**.

Для новичков рекомендую web api

Comment: Вы можете подсказать русскоязычную литературу по REST API и WCF? Лично я так ничего из "свежего" не нашел, все попадаются книги 2005-2008 гг. В чем, также разница между rest api и wcf, и какие популярные технологии есть еще в разработке клиент-серверных приложений?